# if we write same property in component CSS or scss file and root CSS or scss file in angular 8 project then which one will execute?

Tags: css, angular, angular8, angular-components, scss-mixins

As I write same property with different values in root scss file and in one component of my project. I am confusing which one will execute. Please help me.

Comment: Both will "execute". Which one will actually be applied depends on the CSS selector specificity.

Answer (score 1):

In angular, there is a concept called **view encapsulation** which in simple terms means that *whatever styles you write in your component stays in the component*. Styles in comp A cant be used in comp B.

**If you import the global style into your component scss** then it will be affecting your component unless you modify or overwrite within your component. For ex:

If global styles have .card { padding: 0} and you imported global styles in your component. Then if you write .card { margin: 0} then in the end .card applied in your component html will be as below

```
.card {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The local css will always override the general style.css. Think of it as the general css is applicated, then the local will be applicated upon it. Here is an example demontrating this behavior : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rqrngi?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: If i write !important with that property in root css file, then what will happen?

Comment: @NarunDutta Why don't you try it? `!important` will win. The most specific CSS selector will win, keeping in mind Angular adds local css and html attributes.

Comment: local css will not always override general style.css. You need to use :host or ::ng-deep selector to do it. Or to use !important foreach css attribute.

Comment: I was refering to "normal" uses case. if you use !important or ::ng-deep, this is another story. Also, if I suspect that the author of the question don't know about those concept if we refer to his question....